# LINQ GroupBy-Rank-Sum

Tags: linq

I'm trying to write a piece of LINQ code that will allow me to extract information from an object that essentially consists of an expanded list containing 2 string properties and a dictionary property, where the ditionary is of type `<string, double>`, for each line in the List.

I have tried various combinaitons of GroupBy, Select, Sum and have scoured the other threads for something similar but all other dictionary related questions appear to have few layers of complexity.

My goal is to group the data in the List object by the first string property, and then subtotal one of the Dictionary entries for each of the grouped strings from step 1. I then want to take the top 5 subtotals from the dictionary by grouped string from step1.

```
        var result = List<ListObject>
            .Where(i => i.string2 == "June")
            .GroupBy(i => i.string1)
            .Sum(i => i.Sum(s => s.Values.TryGetValue("Value1",0.0))
           .Take(5));

Also adding the ListObject definition as requested

public class ListObject{
    public string string1{ get; set; }
    public string string2{ get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, double> Values { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Could you post the class definition for the ListObject variable?

Comment: `ListObject.Where` doesn't make any sense, since `ListObject` is a class.  What are you starting from?  A single `ListObject` or a `List<ListObject>`?

Comment: A little clearer - we're starting with a list of type <ListObject>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you might be looking for something like this:

```
var los = new List<ListObject>();
string sumField = "Value1";

var result = los
    .Where(lo => lo.string2 == "June")
    .GroupBy(lo => lo.string1)
    .Select(g => new {
        Key = g.Key,
        Total = g
            .Where(x => x.Values.ContainsKey(sumField))
            .Sum(s => s.Values[sumField]),
    })
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Total)
    .Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
someEnumerable.GroupBy(e => e.SomeDictionary.Values.Sum());
```